# Linear Combination Definition Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra stuff and stuck at this problem right now.

[image]

It seems like a new user is not allowed to post the image directly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

My understanding for this problem is that BCDEF are all correct since they are essentially just in a format of $au + bv$, which apparently are wrong.

Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: B, C, D, E, and F are all correct, but your answer is not.  Can you see why or do you need more help?

Comment: A is also true. They asked to select *all* of the vectors that are linear combination. Marking BCDEF is only some of the vectors, but not all.

Comment: It would be much better if you entered your question as text instead of posting a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. MathJax is used here for formatting mathematical expressions. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u,v$ are linearly independent vectors they form a basis and span the space $\mathbb R^2$

a) is true.

b,c,d,e,f) are all vectors in $\mathbb R^2,$ which means that they must also be true.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mark $A$ which is also correct. Note that the two given vectore are linearly independent so they span the whole $R^2$